# Django detect errors while sending mail

Tags: python, django, email

```
def send_one_mail(request):
   send_mail('The subject', 'The body to testing', 'userone@example.com',['usertwo@gmail.com'],    fail_silently=False)
   return HttpResponse("This mail has sent successfull")
```

And my settings.py is

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'userone@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'userone@example.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'userone@example.com'
```

I have a view (which works) as shown above, here userone@example.com is sender and usertwo@gmail.com
is the receiver.

How can i check and act according to errors in sending mail?
(I want to show "Some error occured" in such errors)

How can i determine if the usertwo@gmail.com(reciver) exists or not?
(if email can't be reached, i want to show the user that the email doesn't exist)

I am using postfix,dovecot etc. in server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick up some errors when you use fail_silently = False. Just wrap send_mail in try/except.

When i wanted more control over e-mail sending, then i stopped using django mailing completely and installed lamson instead (lamsonproject.org). You can basically create your own mail server with it, attach your django orm to it and provide detailed feedback about what has happened to your e-mails. If you insert some kind of downloadable content into those e-mails (like images), then you can even give hashes to images and verify this way if e-mail has been opened too. You could do that with django based email sending too. Lamson just gives bit more control over the what and how that goes on after you hit send button.

Comment: I think you are right. But still waiting for any other answers too. But do you have any idea about exeption regarding the particular case? Is there any neat documentation for the send_mail function?

Comment: Best documentation is to read the source code. Most often you will be using mail with smtp backend (which is default) and it does not have special Exception classes - you can check by yourself by opening django.core.mail.backends.smtp. So the error message could be any of the smtp errors : http://email.about.com/cs/standards/a/smtp_error_code.htm. But in most cases the errors are: Wrong adderss (which you can elliminate by using EmailField) or wrong domain name - mail server will reject message if the doman name is something like myfunnydomainnamewhichdoesnotexist.net.

Comment: All other errors come with bounces, and you can't return those with view anyway because they are received by your mail server when end-point mail server responds with something like -address does not exist nor mailbox over quota.

Comment: **So there is no way to handle bounces?** For example when a <to@address> which doesn't exists given.  On going through the net, i got the idea to use python's package validate_email,[link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email), to validate. **Is it a good idea to use such packages with django?**

Comment: You can always program postfix to do something with bounces. But in my opinion, using project like lamsonproject is much easyer. Using package like the one you linked is not very good idea, because users expect the page loads to be near instant and such packages essentially block the view to do what they are doing. Sure it might be long time most often, but it takes little to trigger users anger.  Essentially you are trying to use UX problem here - how to make sure that user gets proper feedback at proper time. And most users know that they will not recieve letter if they enter incorrect email

Comment: So you do not need to create very elaborate solution here. I'm sure simple django send_email will work. If you want to give more feedback, then consider using lamson to get more control over sending e-mail and handling bounces. But perhaps you do not need even that.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be the final words. I will surely make try to lamsonproject. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### django-mail-queue

Anyway, i finally ended-up with using the below package.

```
pip install django-mail-queue
```

And here is the docs

https://django-mail-queue.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: A side note, if someone is using django-mail-queue, I think, you should consider logging. I had some exceptions unnoticed (ie.with no exceptions thrown), which was silenced after logging that exception.